# p element's length same as text in it?

Tags: html, css, paragraph

I simply want all of my p elements to be the length of the text in it. It works if I put `.intro p` at `inline-block`, but I would like my p elements all to be displayed underneath each other. Is there a way to do this?

HTML:

```
<div class="intro">
    <p>fjsdqk  dhksjfd kjsh kdshjkd</p>
    <p>hsdqjkf kjdsh</p>
    <p>hdsqkhfj sdhkjf fsjqkfhdks  hjs</p>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.intro {
    margin-top: 80px;
    color: #ffffff;
    text-align: center;
}

.intro p {
    margin-bottom: 12px;
    padding: 6px 12px;
    background: #25d6a2;
}
```

Comment: Mind explaining *why* you need to know the length of the text? Seems an unusual thing to need to know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add `br` tag after each `p` element

```
<div class="intro">
    <p>fjsdqk  dhksjfd kjsh kdshjkd</p><br>
    <p>hsdqjkf kjdsh</p><br>
    <p>hdsqkhfj sdhkjf fsjqkfhdks  hjs</p><br>
</div>
```

<kbd>[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/LwBQL/)</kbd>

---

If you don't want to add `<br />` in the DOM or for some reason you cannot modify your HTML, you can simulate line break using CSS `:after` pseudo with `content` property having an value of `\a` and `white-space` set to `pre`

As far as the explanation goes for `\a`, its an hexadecimal value for line feed which is equivalent to `10`.

```
p:after {
    content:"\a";
    white-space: pre;
}
```

<kbd>[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/LwBQL/1/)</kbd>

Comment: Thank you, this works! Just a question: is this the "correct" way to do this?

Comment: You can do it without HTML

Comment: @2339870 It is correct but am not sure why you want to make all your `p` elements inline...

Comment: Otherwise their backgrounds fill up the whole space of my screen. Of what exactly do you mean?

Comment: @2339870 Ya so you can follow my solution, its fine

Comment: `<br>` means line break. According to HTML5 CR, it should be used only when the data itself (such as an address) contains a line break.

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela It's not invalid though

Comment: @Mr.Alien, no, just illogical and clumsy: it requires adding markup elements for the purpose of formatting `p` elements.

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela Yea but the requirement is clumsy as well, and hence I asked OP that am not sure why he wants to do that, so I've provided an alternate solution :) or he can use `span` elements set to `display: block;` after each `p` element...

Answer (score 0):

In a sense, you want to eat your cake and keep it: make the `p` elements inline elements as far as box formatting is considered (in this case, for the purpose of setting background behind the text only) but block elements in the sense of starting on a fresh line.

There are various methods and tricks, but perhaps the simplest one is to use floating (instead of `display: inline-block`): float the elements to the left but also clear floating, so that no real floating takes place—you just want the side effect of floating, the effect of making the element just as wide as its content requires:

```
.intro p {
    float: left;
    clear: both;
}
```

In addition, you need to set `clear: both` on the element after the intro.

Comment: Why not just block instead of inline?

Comment: @AliGajani, `display: block` makes the `p` element as wide as the available space permits, against a basic requirement in the question.